# How to show function prototype in Emacs?

Tags: c, emacs, etag

While in C-mode I can jump to a function using M-. on the function name....is there a way i can simply display the function prototype? (preferably as a tooltip or so) I often struggle to remember the exact order and types required by a given function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

c-eldoc-mode is a mode that is not as heavyweight as CEDET that will do precisely what you want.

Comment: c-eldoc-mode is exactly what i wanted :) CEDET was a bit too bulky and slow for me...:) thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) (there are rumors that it is finally going to become part of Emacs starting with 23.2) is your friend. After installation, look up `semantic-ia-show-summary`.

Comment: not just rumors - it's been integrated with the CVS repository, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

CEDET package provide function semantic-ia-show-summary that can show prototype for function/variable under point